# Is there a way to simplify this "While loop" / "For loop" interaction in Python?

Tags: python, for-loop, while-loop

```
  for a in list:
        answer_or_help = False
        print(a.question)
        while answer_or_help not in ("q", "a"):
                answer_or_help = input("Press a for Answer, h for Help, q to quit: ")
                if answer_or_help == "h":
                        print(a.hint)
                elif answer_or_help == "a":
                        print(a.answer)
                elif answer_or_help != "q":
                        print("This is not a valid answer")
        else:
                if answer_or_help == "q":
                        break
```

I'm trying to exit the FOR loop when I type "q" and I'm not sure this is the best way to do it.

I would appreciate any help. Thank you!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have one question per object. You don't need a `while`. `input()` function will wait indefinitely for the user input.

```
idx = 0
while idx < len(your_list):
    
    obj = your_list[idx]
    
    print(obj.question)
    answer_or_help = input("Press a for Answer, h for Help, q to quit: ")
    
    if answer_or_help == 'q':
        break
    
    elif answer_or_help == "h":
        print(obj.hint)
        
    elif answer_or_help == "a":
         print(obj.answer)
         idx += 1 # moving object

    else:
        print("This is not a valid answer")
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I forgot to mention that I need to stay in the same FOR loop instance when entering h. Basically:

- If "a" print answer and go to the next question
- If "h" print hint but stay
- If "q" exit the test
- If "anything else" print error and stay

Comment: Much appreciated it

Answer (score 0):

You can do these actions with **break**, **continue**, and **pass** statements.
**Break Statement**
In Python, the break statement provides you with the opportunity to exit out of a loop when an external condition is triggered. You’ll put the break statement within the block of code under your loop statement, usually after a conditional if statement.

```
 number = 0

for number in range(10):
    if number == 5:
        break    # break here

    print('Number is ' + str(number))

print('Out of loop')
```

**Continue Statement**
The continue statement gives you the option to skip over the part of a loop where an external condition is triggered, but to go on to complete the rest of the loop. That is, the current iteration of the loop will be disrupted, but the program will return to the top of the loop.

The continue statement will be within the block of code under the loop statement, usually after a conditional if statement.

```
number = 0

for number in range(10):
    if number == 5:
        continue    # continue here

    print('Number is ' + str(number))

print('Out of loop')
```

**Pass Statement**
When an external condition is triggered, the pass statement allows you to handle the condition without the loop being impacted in any way; all of the code will continue to be read unless a break or other statement occurs.

As with the other statements, the pass statement will be within the block of code under the loop statement, typically after a conditional if statement.

```
  number = 0

for number in range(10):
    if number == 5:
        pass    # pass here

    print('Number is ' + str(number))

print('Out of loop')
```

Comment: Thanks for all the details about pass/continue/break, however, testing those without a "while" loop, I'm still unable to reach my goal:

- a -> print answer and go to next question
- h -> print hint but stay in the current question
- q -> Exit the test
- anything else -> print error

Answer (score -1):

I'd wrap it in a function, so you can return from it.

```
def show_questions(questions):
    for item in questions:
        print(item.question)
        while True:
            user_input = input("Press a for Answer, h for Help, q to quit: ")
            if user_input == 'h':
                print(item.hint)
            elif user_input == 'a':
                print(item.answer)
                break
            elif user_input == 'q':
                return
            else:
                print("This is not a valid answer)
```

Note how you can clearly see the difference between answering `a`, `h` and `q` this way: `h` keeps you in the inner loop, `a` breaks the inner loop and `q` breaks both loops by returning from the function.

Comment: Thanks for your help.

I was planning to move this into a function, I've tested it and it works. I suppose I can't make it shorter than that.

Thanks again